On onnxruntime-gpu,CUDAProvider,Some nodes were not assigned to the preferred execution providers which may or may not have an negative impact on perf
I have been facing an issue when I am trying to inference using a dynamically quantized yolov8s onnx model on GPU.
I have used yolov8s.pt and exported it to yolov8.onnx using onnx export. Then I quantized the onnx model using dynamic quantization (uint8) method provided by onnxruntime which reduced the model size by around 4 times. Though the quantized model worked fine while inferencing on CPU (CPUExecutionProvider), it gives low fps (frames per sec) while inferencing on GPU using CUDAExecutionProvider.
Mentioning both providers CUDAExecutionProvider and CPUExecutionProvider,
providers=['CUDAExecutionProvider','CPUExecutionProvider']
does make the warnings disappear but what I am concerned is about why some nodes are forcefully being executed on the CPU and not CUDA? Is it because CUDA does not yet provide support for such quantized nodes or is there any other particular reason for it?
This is the warning shown
When checked using log.severity, got this information
import onnxruntime as ort
ort.set_default_logger_severity(1)
output of log information image-1
output of log information image-2
I am curious about why CUDA is not able to handle these nodes? Because in my opinion it is very unusual to see GPU inference giving a lower fps as compared to CPU inference. Is there any solution to run all the nodes exclusively on CUDA?
Github issue :- Link to the issue where I commented
